# How can I have google place picker look as my app's theme?

Tags: android, material-design, gmsplacepicker

I want to use google place picker in my app. I have followed this link 
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker
and added place picker in my fragment but it dose not get the color or theme of my app. The toolbar of place picker shows white in color.

Its written in document that the picker takes colorPrimary from the material theme of app. I also have a `colorPimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` im my `style.xml`.

What's going wrong here?

**code:**

```
public class NameOfBusinessFragment extends Fragment {

    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    int RESULT_OK = -1;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    EditText category,location;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name_of_business,
                    container, false);

            location = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.location);

            location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {

                        startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                    }
                    catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ServiceRepaire Exception",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException  e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SeerviceNotAvailable Exception",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());
                String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                location.setText(place.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Style.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

How to get this?

Comment: You got any solution for this problem? Apparently I also facing the same issue on 4.2.2. devices. It seems to work fine on 5.1.1 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

with:

```
Intent placePickerIntent = builder.build(getActivity());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    placePickerIntent.putExtra("primary_color", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    placePickerIntent.putExtra("primary_color_dark", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
}
startActivityForResult(placePickerIntent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

The place picker doesn't automatically pick color from the theme. It is a bug as discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7968). Also note that this is a hack and not an actual clean solution.

Comment: I tried by only starting an intent for the other app, and it picked the theme color automatically on same device. No idea what's wrong for other app i have same styles with both the apps. @Obscure Geek

Comment: Interesting. Same style and same device. Are the design and app-compat library versions also same?

Comment: yes, I have just changed the package name of the app, And further changed the activities and design as needed. and when I tried to implement place picker same as previous app, it worked. Still not working for previous app. @Obscure Geek

Comment: You tried the posted solution for the previous app?

Comment: could you please help me with this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959739/how-to-get-contacts-photo-by-contacts-number @Obscure Geek